# Parse, pattern match and extract functions of variables

Tags: pattern-matching

From expressions like `i σ[1, 1] + p ** x σ[1, 1]`, I want to be able to extract and separate any functions of `p` and `x`. For example, it would return a list of triplets `{i,σ [1, 1], 1}, {1,σ[1, 1], p ** x}`, but it should work for generic polynomial functions of `x` and `p`. Is this possible?

I want to be able to pattern match a product like `A p**p** ... x**x ... **x` where `A` is the coefficient and the noncommutative product is always ordered with `p` before `x` but has an unknown number of terms `x` and `p`.

More examples:

```
p**p**x 2y -> {2y, 1, p**p**x} 
 
σ[1,1] 2y -> {2y, σ[1,1], 1}
  
g -> {g, 1, 1}  

p -> {1, 1, p}

p**p**x -> {1, 1, p**p**x}
```

Comment: Does `Cases[expr, a_. NonCommutativeMultiply[___, p, ___, x, ___]]` work for you?

Comment: @Domen yes thanks I think I figured it out

Comment: @Domen is there a way to make it return 1 when a match is not found? I am using the rule /. a_ s_\[Sigma] NonCommutativeMultiply[i___, p, j___, x, k___] -> {a,s,NonCommutativeMultiply[i, p, j, x, k]}
but sometimes a, s or NonCommutative... may be missing, in which case I want a 1 in the list

Comment: Can you please edit the question and include an example of your expression? The one that contains both kind of terms.

Answer (score 0):

```
expr = i σ[1, 1] + p ** x σ[1, 1]
Cases[expr, Optional[a_, 1] (σ : σ[__]) *
 (b : NonCommutativeMultiply[___, p, ___, x, ___]) | 
 (Optional[a_, 1] (σ : σ[__]) b_ : 1) :> {a, σ, b}]
(* {{i, σ[1, 1], 1}, {1, σ[1, 1], p ** x}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. for some reason Cases[p ** x, NonCommutativeMultiply[___, p, ___, x, ___]] doesn't work when it is only an expression of p and x on its own. it also doesn't work for Cases[p, NonCommutativeMultiply[___, p, ___, x, ___]]. Is there a way to make Cases[p, NonCommutativeMultiply[___, p, ___, x, ___]] return p instead of {}?

Comment: That's why I told you to please include all possible types of expressions and expected output in your question above :) I'll fix my answer after you do that.

Comment: Thanks, I found a way by just using cases to extract the expression and add it to a list and then delete it one by one. For example I extract p\*\*x and then delete it and then do the same for $\sigma$. But for some reason Cases does not work when the expression is just the symbol I am looking for. For example Cases[p,p] returns {}